# how to invoke external restful webservice(retuns JSON data) from webscript and display the data on dashlet?

Tags: alfresco

JSON data :

```
{"user":[{"address":"HYD0","id":"0","name":"XXXX0"},
         {"address":"HYD1","id":"1","name":"XXXXX1"},
         {"address":"HYD2","id":"2","name":"XXXXXX2"}]}
```

so how should i call restful webservice in webscript and display the data on free marker template and dashlet?

the rest web service placed some where, now i want to invoke it from web script.

Comment: To clarify, is your question asking how you can make a call to an external JSON REST api (not on the repo) from your webscripts JavaScript model, so you can display the resulting data in the ftl?

Comment: Yes, I need to get the above json data as a response in javascript web script then i have to display it on ftl. i am trying with        XMLHttpRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/Customers/getAll",false, "admin", "admin");
 XMLHttpRequest.send("");
 so which method should i use to get json data and where to set the model?

Answer (score 1):

When working in Share, Surf provides a way to access other systems to fetch data. This is done via the `remote` object, and if you look at many of the Share WebScripts you'll see things like:

```
var connector = remote.connect("alfresco");
var result = connector.get("/api/foo/bar?thing=stuff");
if (result.status == status.STATUS_OK)
{
   return eval('(' + result.response + ')');
}
```

The `remote` object in JavaScript is provided by the [ScriptRemote](https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/spring-surf-parent/apidocs/org/springframework/extensions/webscripts/ScriptRemote.html) object. If you browse the source for that, you'll see how it all works and fits together

The most common use is with the *alfresco* endpoint, which connects back to the Alfresco Repository tier so you can call repo webscripts. One option is for you to define your own endpoint to Share via the spring config, then you can access that with a friendly name. The other is to do what the [RSS Feed Utils](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/slingshot/config/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/utils/feed.utils.js) does and request the `http` endpoint, then give a full URL.

Either way, you'll want to fetch the remote URL, check you got a valid response, eval it to get the data, and store that in your model. That data will then be available in the FTL to render as you want.